# draw() method not working with multiple tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have strange situation with `table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw()` method. It works with one of the table on the same page but not for the other.

Please see [this example](http://live.datatables.net/wecoyiqi/1) for demonstration.

Comment: Can you at least make the fiddle working?

Comment: Your code in fiddle is working as expected.

Comment: where is issus?

Comment: Updated link : http://live.datatables.net/wecoyiqi/1/edit

@jay  Problem is with first table when i click on हटाये (btnremove)button on first row design crashes.Same thing working perfectly with Second table.
Please help !!!